# Can't launch emulator from genymotion

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I use Ubuntu 20.04
I installed genymotion and virtual box from official sites.
When I installed first time genymotion emulator launched after few attempts. After few days didn't launch any more. I tried reinstall virtual box but it doesn't helped to me. I searched on the internet but I didn't find anything what fixed my problem.

When I launch emulator from genymotion it shows me this error:
[image]

When I launch this machine from virtual box it show me this error:

[image]

**UPD:** Also I have VMware Player on my machine. Maybe it's interrupt it, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the instructions from Genymotion help center article: https://support.genymotion.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002718198-Unable-to-start-the-Virtual-Device ?

Comment: Most of them for windows, but I use ubuntu 20.04. Some of them I checked for example my Virtualization is enabled. I tried to reinstall many times. I deleted everything from Host Network Manager. Anything didn't helped to me. Also I deleted VMware Player, tried to update OS, it didn't helped to me

Comment: In the log I see this line
00:00:00.888692 nspr-2   NetIfAdpCtlOut: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while retrieving link speed for wlp3s0: VBoxNetAdpCtl: ioctl failed: Operation not supported

Comment: Are you sure VirtualBox kernel module is installed and working? To verify, try `modinfo vboxdrv` - it should return something like `version: 6.1.26_Ubuntu r145957 (0x00300000)`. If it says that the module cannot be found, you probably need to rebuild it with this command:

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install virtualbox-dkms`

One more thing: you are running Ubuntu natively, right? You're not using a VM, are you?

Comment: I checked with modinfo vboxdrv and it return version of virtual box. I attempt many times, but I can't fix my problem  then I can solve my task with android emulator. But needed virtual box to use genymotion. But can't fixed virtual box then I deleted virtual box and genymotion.